# Window function without ORDER BY

Tags: postgresql

There is a window function without `ORDER BY` in `OVER ()` clause. Is there a guarantee that the rows will be processed in the order specified by the `ORDER BY` expression in SELECT itself?

For example:

```
SELECT tt.*
     , row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY tt."group") AS npp --without ORDER BY
FROM
  (
   SELECT SUBSTRING(random() :: text, 3, 1) AS "group"
        , random() :: text          AS "data"
   FROM generate_series(1, 100) t(ser)
   ORDER BY "group", "data"
  ) tt
ORDER BY tt."group", npp;
```

In this example the subquery returns the `data` sorted in ascending order in each group. The window function handles the rows in the same order, and so the line numbers go in ascending order of the `data`. Can I rely on this?

Comment: the short answer is "no".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good question!

No, you cannot rely on that.

Window functions are processed *before* the query's `ORDER BY` clause, and without an `ORDER BY` in the window definition, the rows will be processed in the order in which they happen to come from the subselect.